# Why is answer 18946 deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-post

Can any one tell why [this answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/18945/did-yazid-order-to-kill-imam-hossein-a-s/18946#18946) is deleted?

Comment: @down-voters, really Why?

Comment: And the down-vote, from me at least, is because this meta post shows absolutely no indication that you have either read the feedback that was already provided to you, what if anything you misunderstood about the feedback that was already provided to you, or why you chose to disregard the feedback that was already provided to you.

Comment: @goldPseudo By the feedback, if you mean the comment, It was just an opinion or a unidirectional discussion, nothing more!

Comment: @goldPseudo Every day a new way for deleting the posts! Do you really consider constructive criticisms?

Comment: You wanted to know why I deleted the post: I told you.  You wanted to know why I downvoted you: I told you.  Instead of wasting time arguing about that, why don't you try to improve the post and maybe convince someone to undelete instead?

Answer (score -1):

The post was deleted because it basically did nothing to answer the question.  The question was asking for proof, but the answer did not provide it: It just made a claim ("Yes it was Yazid who ordered…") and listed a bunch of narrations.

Absolutely no attempt was made to establish either the credibility or the authenticity of these narrations, nor indicate what if any relevance they had to answering the actual question.  They're simply…there.

Without any indication that these narrations are credible, the *only* support they provide to your claim is in their quantity; there's a lot of them, so they *must* be right.  However, this support is entirely an illusion based on selective bias: Presenting only evidences that support a claim while wholly ignoring evidences that go against it is a prime example of the [cherry-picking fallacy](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1438/22).

And in the case of this answer, in lieu of any argument to the *quality* of the evidences, the quantity alone proves *absolutely nothing*.  A half-dozen, a dozen, even a hundred weak evidences are nothing to a single *credible* report which contradicts them.  If you want the quantity alone to support your claim — a strategy I would very much not recommend — you would still need to present a compelling argument that credible counter-evidence *does not exist*.

Your post didn't provide that either.

And even if — and I'm stressing the **if** here — any of these evidences are credible and/or authentic, or credible counter-evidence does not exist, there is absolutely no attempt made to establish *relevance*: Why is quoting all four narrations verbatim — in Arabic *and* in English — even necessary?  What makes four better than one?  What makes full quotations better than in-line references?   If one evidence can demonstrably prove a position, there's no need to bring in four, but if one evidence *can't* prove a position, what reason is there to even include it?  Again, as presented it just simply looks like you're trying to emphasize the *quantity* rather than anything else.

Given that this list-of-evidences does nothing to actually bolster your claim, despite taking up *three-quarters of your post*, the whole thing pretty much looks like an attempt to push apologetic rather than any attempt to answer an actual practical question, which is [not what the site is for](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1255/22).

Comment: Are all the criteria that you required for this answer supposed to hold for every question asking for historical proof? I think few historical questions can satisfy these criteria within SE model, for conclusively addressing all aspects of historical questions often require very lengthy discussions that can fill pages and pages, too long for a typical answer in SE.

Comment: @infatuated if asking for historical proof is out of scope for the site, then the problem is with the question which is *explicitly asking for it*; you should bring that up as a separate meta discussion (but see also the related discussion at http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/274/22).  As it stands, the question is asking for *historical proof*, and the answer *is not providing it*.

Comment: Yes, it does seem to be a tricky challenge to work out a solution for historical questions. (I may write a meta about it in future.) But as for this specific answer, while I agree that it fails to satisfy some of the criteria we except from an answer of historical nature, yet I can hardly convince myself that it provides "no proof" at all. The quotes (provided that they are authentic) in my eyes do lend themselves in supporting the user's thesis. But one can reasonably argue it is still not strong enough to be a conclusive and definitive judgement.

Comment: It was not just a bunch of narrations, but historical proof from authenticated sources.

Comment: Again another unidirectional discussion which proves nothing! where can I have such a long answer to your claims?

Comment: @MohammadHossein, In meta you can write a separate answer in response to another.