# Please can you only link to fatwas when giving information

Tags: discussion, fatwa

I don't mean to say this to hurt or offend anyone, because your help is excellent. However a scholarly opinion is the best sought, I'm saying this so as to help you.

Answer (score 4):

Scholarly opinions are exactly that: Opinions.  And depending on what the questioner wants, there's no reason to believe those opinions are any more or less valid just because they come from a scholar (this often falls afoul of the "Appeal to Authority" fallacy, see also: [What is a fallacy, and why is it so bad?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1438/22)).

The onus is on the questioner to ask their question in such a way as to attract the right answers.  Unless the question explains exactly *which* scholarly opinion it wants (or if it even *wants* one in the first place), presenting opinions the questioner *doesn't* ask for, just because they're from fatwas, doesn't really help them.  And if we as a site are only asking questions that can already be answered by existing linkable fatawa, then we're really not making the Internet a better place, we're just regurgitating the same information that's already out there.