# Why was my answer deleted for question "How should punishment be carried out for stoning?"?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answer

I had an answer on the question:

[How should stoning be carried out?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12038/how-should-punishment-be-carried-out-for-stoning/27595?noredirect=1#comment47117_27595)

Which answers the question that was asked:

> I am confused here: I understand that the stoning comes from the hadith and not the quran (Where do we get the idea of beheading, stoning and hand-mutilation in Islam?), but where does it say how the stoning should be done?

May I have some info on why my answer was deleted as:

> This does absolutely nothing to answer the question asked. We are not a site for pushing your personal opinions and Truth on others.

When indeed the answer does tell where the "how stoning should be done" comes from?

Answer (score 2):

The post as written was clearly trying to push anti-stoning polemic ([which is wholly unacceptable here](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1255/22)) and pretty much the *entirety* of your post that was original content was irrelevant to the *actual* question asked. If I were to remove all the [Truth](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1591/22) from your post, all that would remain would be:

> The how comes from a [sahih Muslim hadith](http://sunnah.com/muslim/29/35) where:
>
> > ثُمَّ أَمَرَ بِهَا فَحُفِرَ لَهَا إِلَى صَدْرِهَا وَأَمَرَ النَّاسَ فَرَجَمُوهَا
> >
> > ...And she was put in a ditch up to her chest and he commanded people and they stoned her...

This is not an answer: [Evidences don't speak for themselves](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1475/22). The question is asking *how* the stoning is to be done, whereas the hadith just says "…and they stoned her…" which does not really explain anything.

The *only* aspect of the question which is actually touched on by your answer is the mention of the ditch (as the question mentions the punished being dug into the ground), but it ignores pretty much everything else; the question for example explicitly expressed confusion about hair-covering, which you did not even touch upon.

As written, the whole post looked to be nothing more than an attempt to push your opinions on others than any honest attempt to actually answer the question asked. So I deleted it.