# Deleting answer by moderator even after providing evidence that he is wrong!

Tags: discussion, plagiarism, specific-post

I have answered a question here
https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30457/bi-sexuality-allowed?noredirect=1#comment52605_30457

and have provided references and have mentioned authors names and sections numbers in the reference

@goldPseudo came and deleted my answer because he think I have added reference without mentioning the author names

here is the reference

**al-Tirmidhi (1456)**, **Abu Dawood (4462)**and **Ibn Maajah (2561)** narrated that **Ibn ‘Abbaas** (may Allaah be pleased with him) said: The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Whoever you find doing the action of the people of Loot, execute the one who does it and the one to whom it is done.”. **Classed as saheeh by al-Albaani in Saheeh al-Tirmidhi.**

**Ahmad (2915)** narrated from **Ibn ‘Abbaas** (may Allaah be pleased with him) that the Prophet of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “May Allaah curse the one who does the action of the people of Loot, may Allaah curse the one who does the action of the people of Loot,” three times. This was classed as hasan by **Shu’ayb al-Arna’oot in Tahqeeq al-Musnad.**

the bold sections are the authors names, sections numbers and the narrated personals names also

I need to know why my answer have been deleted ??

Answer (score 5):

I notice how you conveniently forgot to quote the *third* contended paragraph. For your convenience, I'll quote that here:

> The Sahaabah were unanimously agreed on the execution of homosexuals, but they differed as to how they were to be executed. Some of them were of the view that they should be burned with fire, which was the view of ‘Ali (may Allaah be pleased with him) and also of Abu Bakr (may Allaah be pleased with him), as we shall see below. And some of them thought that they should be thrown down from a high place then have stones thrown at them. This was the view of Ibn ‘Abbaas (may Allaah be pleased with him).

A [fairly simple Google search](https://www.google.ca/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22The+Sahaabah+were+unanimously+agreed+on+the+execution+of+homosexuals%22) brings up literally *hundreds* of hits with that *exact* wording. As best I can tell, the original source was [this article from IslamQA](https://islamqa.info/en/38622), a source which you absolutely *did not* cite.

Not only that, but the linked article *also* includes *both* of the previous ahadith that you are claiming that *you* properly attributed. With *exactly* the same translation, arranged in *exactly* the same order, cited with *exactly* the same wording.

[image]

<sup>(screenshot courtesy of copyscape.com)</sup>

Literally **72%** of your post was by all appearances a *direct* [copy-paste from a third-party article](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/953/22), which is bad enough. As was the fact that you just quoted a bunch of "evidences" with absolutely [no attempt at critical explanation](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1475/22) or analysis. As was the fact that you were using these evidences to support a position that the [original author doesn't even accept](https://islamqa.info/en/21058). Oh, yeah, and the fact that you absolutely [refused to give any credit to the third-party](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/193/22) who actually did the work in the first place.

The level of academic dishonesty here is substantial. Frankly, I'd be surprised if you're even a scholar at all, much less qualified to actually derive fatawa from primary sources.

So, yeah, deleted for plagiarism. Exactly as I clearly explained in the comment I left when I deleted it.

Comment: You simply had the chance to delete the part that you referred to and left the part that clearly has his own reference, the part that has hadith doesn't require mentioning the website that came from because simply it has his own sole origin which is hadith books and actually the original speaker is the Prophet Muhammad, so that's more than enough as original auther name but it seems like you just read what you like to read and just close your eyes on the other facts

Comment: to avoid the misleading in using words, the dishonesty that you have mentioned doesn't apply here, for the reason I have mention in my previous comment, also My original answer didn't contain any references, later someone edited my answer and have added the references, I have reviewed the answer and accept it, I haven't try to review the origin of the second paragraph because I thought it was the editor who have wrote this from his own

Comment: please do not judge my knowledge nor my academic background , you don't know me nor do I , I have seen your social media pages and it is really pathetic that someone like you be moderator on islamic discussion board, I think it is my fault to involve in such a place which obviously doesn't care about choosing people who have authority over islamic discussion, you are totally free to remove all posts, answers and comments related to me, actually you can delete my account in this place, I wouldn't involve in any discussion again in this place and I am sure that's best for everyone